# I'm trying to add sql statements into mapper in java spring but gets an error when I try to

Tags: java, mybatis

At first, I thought it was the controller problem and tried to add the ID of those statements, but errors still pop up. code with the problem is around the middle of the code. works fine with ones above.

I can't figure out how to work this thing :( been struggling for hours now.
any help would be really appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="egovframework.example.sample.service.impl.SampleMapper">

    <resultMap id="sample" type="egovframework.example.sample.service.sampleVO">
        <result property="id" column="id"/>
        <result property="name" column="name"/>
        <result property="description" column="description"/>
        <result property="useYn" column="use_yn"/>
        <result property="regUser" column="reg_user"/>
        <result property="regDate" column="regdate"/>
        <result property="hit" column="hit"/>
        <result property="orifile" column="orifile"/>
        <result property="servfile" column="servfile"/>
        <result property="email" column="email"/>
        <result property="step" column="step"/>
        <result property="depth" column="depth"/>
        <result property="ref" column="ref"/>
    </resultMap>

    <insert id="insertSample" parameterType="sampleVO">
<!--    this is inserting without files -->
            INSERT INTO SAMPLE
                ( ID
                  , NAME
                  , DESCRIPTION
                  , EMAIL
                  , REG_USER
                  , PASS
                  , IP
                  , REF)
            VALUES ( #{id}
                  , #{name}
                  , #{description}
                  , #{email}
                  , #{regUser}
                  , #{pass}
                  , #{ip}
                  , #{id})

    </insert>


    <update id="hit" parameterType="sampleVO">
    update sample set hit = hit + 1 where id = #{id}

    </update>

    <update id="updateSample" parameterType="sampleVO">
            UPDATE SAMPLE
            SET
<!--            ID=#{id} -->
<!--                ,  -->
                NAME=#{name}
                , DESCRIPTION=#{description}
                , USE_YN=#{useYn}
                  WHERE ID=#{id}

    </update>

    <delete id="deleteSample" parameterType="sampleVO">
            DELETE FROM SAMPLE
            WHERE ID=#{id}

    </delete>

    <select id="selectSample" resultMap="sample">

            SELECT
                ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, USE_YN, REG_USER, email
            FROM SAMPLE
            WHERE ID=#{id}

    </select>


<!--    <select id="selectSampleList" parameterType="searchVO" -->
    <select id="selectSampleList" parameterType="sampleVO"
    resultType="egovMap">
    select RNUM, ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, USE_YN, REG_USER, REGDATE, HIT, IP,
    REF, STEP, DEPTH FROM (SELECT A.*, ROWNUM RNUM FROM(SELECT * FROM
    SAMPLE ORDER BY REF DESC, STEP ASC)A)

        <![CDATA[
        WHERE RNUM >= (#{firstIndex}+1) AND RNUM <= #{lastIndex}
        ]]>
        <if test="searchKeyword != null and searchKeyword != ''">
            <choose>
                <when test="searchCondition == 0">
                    AND ID LIKE '%' || #{searchKeyword} || '%'
                </when>
                <when test="searchCondition == 1">
                    AND NAME LIKE '%' || #{searchKeyword} || '%'
                </when>
            </choose>
        </if>
<!--        i still dont understand why i have to put in +1.... >:( -->
    </select>

    <select id="selectSampleListTotCnt" parameterType="searchVO" resultType="int">
            SELECT COUNT(*) totcnt
            FROM SAMPLE
            WHERE 1=1
            <if test="searchKeyword != null and searchKeyword != ''">
                <choose>
                    <when test="searchCondition == 0">
                        AND ID LIKE '%' || #{searchKeyword} || '%'
                    </when>
                    <when test="searchCondition == 1">
                        AND NAME LIKE '%' || #{searchKeyword} || '%'
                    </when>
                </choose>
            </if>
    </select>






<!--    


EVERYTHING WORKS FINE UNTIL I ADD SCRIPTS BELOW.

 -->

    <select id="getReply" parameterType="sampleVO" resultType="sample">
<!--        first step: getting data you need to make reply from article ur gonna reply.  -->
        SELECT ID, REF, STEP, DEPTH FROM SAMPLE WHERE ID = #{id}
    </select>

    <update id="stepping" parameterType="sampleVO">
        UPDATE SAMPLE(STEP) VALUES STEP = STEP + 1
        <![CDATA[
        WHERE STEP >= #{step} AND REF = #{ref}
        ]]>
    </update>

    <insert id="addReply" parameterType="sampleVO">
<!--        and insert rply  thingy -->
        INSERT INTO
        BOARD(ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, PASS, REG_USER, REF, IP, EMAIL, STEP, DEPTH)
        VALUES(GOVSEQ.NEXTVAL, #{name}, #{description}, #{pass}, #{regUser},
        #{ref}, #{ip},#{email}, #{step}, #{depth})     
    </insert>




</mapper>
```

---

```
...AND THE ERROR:

05, 2017 10:58:08 오전 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sampleService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sampleMapper' defined in file [C:\eGovFrameDev-3.2.0-64bit\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\board\WEB-INF\classes\egovframework\example\sample\service\impl\SampleMapper.class]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sqlSession' while setting bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSession' defined in file [C:\eGovFrameDev-3.2.0-64bit\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\board\WEB-INF\classes\egovframework\spring\context-mapper.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'file [C:\eGovFrameDev-3.2.0-64bit\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\board\WEB-INF\classes\egovframework\sqlmap\example\mappers\EgovSample_Sample_SQL.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'egovframework.example.sample.service.sampleVO'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: egovframework.example.sample.service.sampleVO
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:633)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5003)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sampleMapper' defined in file [C:\eGovFrameDev-3.2.0-64bit\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\board\WEB-INF\classes\egovframework\example\sample\service\impl\SampleMapper.class]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sqlSession' while setting bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSession' defined in file [C:\eGovFrameDev-3.2.0-64bit\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\board\WEB-INF\classes\egovframework\spring\context-mapper.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'file [C:\eGovFrameDev-3.2.0-64bit\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\board\WEB-INF\classes\egovframework\sqlmap\example\mappers\EgovSample_Sample_SQL.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'egovframework.example.sample.service.sampleVO'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: egovframework.example.sample.service.sampleVO
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:445)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:419)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:304)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSession' defined in file [C:\eGovFrameDev-3.2.0-64bit\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\board\WEB-INF\classes\egovframework\spring\context-mapper.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'file [C:\eGovFrameDev-3.2.0-64bit\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\board\WEB-INF\classes\egovframework\sqlmap\example\mappers\EgovSample_Sample_SQL.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'egovframework.example.sample.service.sampleVO'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: egovframework.example.sample.service.sampleVO
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to parse mapping resource: 'file [C:\eGovFrameDev-3.2.0-64bit\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\board\WEB-INF\classes\egovframework\sqlmap\example\mappers\EgovSample_Sample_SQL.xml]'; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'egovframework.example.sample.service.sampleVO'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: egovframework.example.sample.service.sampleVO
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.buildSqlSessionFactory(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:466)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:340)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'egovframework.example.sample.service.sampleVO'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: egovframework.example.sample.service.sampleVO
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.configurationElement(XMLMapperBuilder.java:120)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.parse(XMLMapperBuilder.java:92)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean.buildSqlSessionFactory(SqlSessionFactoryBean.java:464)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error resolving class. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'egovframework.example.sample.service.sampleVO'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: egovframework.example.sample.service.sampleVO
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.BaseBuilder.resolveClass(BaseBuilder.java:103)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.resultMapElement(XMLMapperBuilder.java:264)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.resultMapElement(XMLMapperBuilder.java:251)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.resultMapElements(XMLMapperBuilder.java:243)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder.configurationElement(XMLMapperBuilder.java:116)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'egovframework.example.sample.service.sampleVO'.  Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: egovframework.example.sample.service.sampleVO
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeAliasRegistry.resolveAlias(TypeAliasRegistry.java:117)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.BaseBuilder.resolveAlias(BaseBuilder.java:130)
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.BaseBuilder.resolveClass(BaseBuilder.java:101)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: egovframework.example.sample.service.sampleVO
    at org.apache.ibatis.io.ClassLoaderWrapper.classForName(ClassLoaderWrapper.java:190)
    at org.apache.ibatis.io.ClassLoaderWrapper.classForName(ClassLoaderWrapper.java:89)
    at org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources.classForName(Resources.java:256)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeAliasRegistry.resolveAlias(TypeAliasRegistry.java:113)
    ... 55 more
```

Comment: The error messages tells a class is missing. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: egovframework.example.sample.service.sampleVO. You should add the class to your classpath (e.g. add the dependency in your pom.xml).

Comment: weird part is that I don't have that class error when i have last 3 parts out. and other statements with no problems all use the same class so there should be no problem reading it.

and of course i checked if I had any <typeAlias> missing, which wasn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your already declared `resultMap` with `id = "sample"` at the top of mapper. In your select statement, you use `resultType = "sample"`. So change your select statement like this

```
<select id="getReply" parameterType="sampleVO" resultMap="sample">
```

Or if you want to use `resultType` instead of `resultMap` then you need to make sure you have a class called `sample` is already created or not.

Comment: d'oh shouldve checked a bit earlier. Just found that problem and got it solved. Thank you very much for the answer. 
and resultmap also had an error inside too(one of the letters was not capitalized).

Answer (score 0):

**1. Above all, check your error logs.**

```
TypeException: Could not resolve type alias 'egovframework.example.sample.service.sampleVO'.  
Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class: egovframework.example.sample.service.sampleVO
```

**2. Add type alias tag for sampleVO class.**

```
<mapper namespace="egovframework.example.sample.service.impl.SampleMapper">
    <typeAlias alias="sampleVO" type="egovframework.example.sample.service.sampleVO" />
    ...
</mapper>
```

This alias is used in the following property.

```
parameterType="sampleVO"
```

**3. Check your path of "sampleVO.java".**

No problem? Next..

**4. Modify following code. type -> class**

```
<resultMap id="sample" type="egovframework.example.sample.service.sampleVO">
```

to

```
<resultMap id="sample" class="egovframework.example.sample.service.sampleVO">
```

Comment: thanks for the advice. I was actually struggling with that error log since I already had it labeled in xml and did not understood why it came out(it was typo).